# How to connect the Redux store to a dynamically created components outside root?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm working on front end admin panel. That allows you to edit each element/widget on site.

There is an admin bar which is connected to Redux and from which you can activate edition. When you click on button edit there are render EditModeButton that are added to each div/widget that has CSS class button-edit-quick-normal on a page. Please see code below.

```
enableEditMode = () => {

    //Catch all of div/widget with class .button-edit-quick-normal
    let buttonEditQuickNormal = [...document.querySelectorAll('.button-edit-quick-normal')];

    //loop through array of DOM elements and render new react component
    buttonEditQuickNormal.map(domContainer => {
        ReactDOM.render(<EditModeButton
            menuType={'quick-normal'}
            handleSingleMenuActivated={this.handleSingleMenuActivated}
            singleMenuActivated={this.state.singleMenuActivated}
        />, domContainer);
    });
 }
```

My Provider looks like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import ThemeApp from 'SBAppsThemes/ThemeApp';
import { SiteEditorPortal } from './index_sitebuilder';
import { AdminbarPortal } from './index_adminbar';


const store = createStore(AppReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f));

       ReactDOM.render(
         <Provider store={store}>
            <React.Fragment>
                <AdminbarPortal />
                <SiteEditorPortal />
            </React.Fragment>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root-react-portals'));
```

And here are Adminbar and SiteEidtorProtal ReactDOM.render:

```
import SiteEditor from 'SBAppsBuilder/containers/SiteEditor';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Root from 'SiteBuilder/boot/root';

export const SiteEditorPortal = () => ReactDOM.createPortal(<SiteEditor/>, document.getElementById('root-sitebuilder'))
```

.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Adminbar from 'SBAppsAdminbar/Adminbar';


export const AdminbarPortal = () => ReactDOM.createPortal(<Adminbar />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**My question is how to add the dynamically created components to the redux store?**

ps. I already connected to separately ReactDOM.render component trough React Portals but in this case, they are created dynamically.

Comment: Where is your provider ?

Comment: @h1b9b I just add how looks like Provider and how I made portal for two components.

Comment: @h1b9b any idea

Comment: actually, I don't understand the question, you want to add a component to your redux store? it so not just dispatch the component in an action and store it using the reducer?

Comment: cause in the code you shared I don't see which component you want to save and when, so I can't help without understanding the problem

Comment: as of the provider, I see that it's englobing both your components so they should have access to the store